What algorithm makes a $2\times 2$ matrix a $3$D curve?
There're set of pictures representing curves around a trefoil. It's described as the image of a matrix in $\mathbb R^3$. How to do that?
The article in section 3.3 explains how to deform a lattice. I've managed to create this flow a while ago. But then article says "there's matrix A, it defines a knot around trefoil". How? What algorithm makes a $2\times2$ matrix a $3$D curve? That is what I'm asking to help me to understand.

For the sake of improving the searchability of this question, Maksim is asking about Étienne Ghys and Jos Leys' Lorenz and modular flows: a visual introduction. This is an exposition of material from Ghys' 2000 paper Knots and dynamics and his 2006 ICM lecture, which was also discussed by Terence Tao and Bruce Westbury.
Anyway, the answer to your question is in section 3.3, although described somewhat tersely:

So, if we define the lattice $L$ to be the image of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by $P$, one finds that $L$ is fixed by $\phi^t$.

This means, explicitly, that starting from a hyperbolic matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, we find its eigenvectors $v_1 = (x_1, y_1), v_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ (necessarily real by hyperbolicity), with eigenvalues $e^t, e^{-t}$ (meaning $A v_i = \lambda_i v_i$), then assemble them into another matrix $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Annoyingly, the desired matrix $P$ is the inverse of this matrix, so this matrix is $P^{-1}$. By construction, it satisfies
$$A P^{-1} = P^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} e^t & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-t} \end{bmatrix}$$
and rearranging this (multiplying by $P$ on the left and on the right) gives
$$\begin{bmatrix} e^t & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-t} \end{bmatrix} P = PA.$$
Since $A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, this implies that if we set $L = P(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ to be the image of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ wrt $P$ (explicitly, this is the lattice spanned by the columns of $P$), then
$$\begin{align*} \begin{bmatrix} e^t & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-t} \end{bmatrix} L &= \begin{bmatrix} e^t & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-t} \end{bmatrix} P(\mathbb{Z}^2) \\
 &= PA(\mathbb{Z}^2) \\
 &= P(\mathbb{Z}^2) = L \end{align*}$$
so $\phi^t$ fixes $L$ (setwise) as claimed. So $L$ is a fixed point of modular flow, meaning modular flow applied to $L$ traces out a closed curve; these are Ghys' "modular knots."
This description does not produce a unique matrix $P$ or a unique lattice $L$ on the nose; the reason is that eigenvectors can be rescaled freely. Even if we restrict our attention to unit area lattices, meaning we require $\det P = 1$, we still have the freedom to scale one of the eigenvectors by $r$ and the other one by $\frac{1}{r}$. Fortunately this is exactly what modular flow does, so the conclusion is that this construction picks out a unique orbit of modular flow; in other words the resulting modular knot only depends on $A$, and in fact only on the conjugacy class of $A$ in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
Here is an explicit calculation for the simplest hyperbolic matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ whose modular knot is pictured in the text:
                                 
WolframAlpha will happily tell you that the eigenvectors of this matrix are $v_1 = \left( \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, 1 \right), v_2 = \left( \frac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}, 1 \right)$. We assemble these into the matrix
$$P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} & \frac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
then invert it, obtaining
$$P = \frac{1}{10} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \sqrt{5} & 5 + \sqrt{5} \\ -2 \sqrt{5} & 5 - \sqrt{5} \end{bmatrix}.$$
So we want the (modular flow of the) lattice $L$ spanned by the two columns of this matrix. Section 3.1 explains in detail how these are being visualized as knots in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Thanks for this clear answer "unknotting" the difficulty... I appreciate very much all your answers.

@Jean: you're very welcome! This is fun material and I'm happy to spread the word.

@QiaochuYuan I didn't realize that I needed to use [e^t, 0, 0, e^−t] * L. Jos Leys provided me with a code which he made with Ghys, for a horocycle from the article, I replaced the orbits, and it works. They're not using Eisenstein series, and there a few tweaks which are not described in this article at all. If you're interested, I can share it. Plus numpy gave me P matrix from the beginning, not P^-1. Maybe the reason that in 3D software vectors in matrices are rows instead of columns, maybe not. It works and that's important. Thank you very much. You're the best

@Maksim: you're welcome! The difference between $P$ and $P^{-1}$ does indeed come down to whether you prefer to act on row or column vectors. It's not too important as long as you keep your conventions consistent.
